# win store app write directly to file

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, xmlwriter

I have a pretty simple question but couldn't find an answer after searching lot of forums.
I have an windows store app which saves the data periodically (using timer) to a xml file. At times, because of system crashing or in case when application is terminated by user in between or by some other exceptions, the xml gets corrupted during the save process (although the data to be saved is valid) and this causes lot of inconsistency. I found a post mentioning that writing data directly to disk (using FileStream's FileOptions.WriteThrough option) but .NET for Win 8 does not have those options.
Is there a way to make sure that xml is never corrupted during all these events and data is saved reliably? I can make copies of files but still want to know if there is any other robust way to handle this.

Below is the code to save xml in timer:-

```
  folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
  stream = await folder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(SystemConfiguration.TASK_XML,CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);      serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tasks));

  using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
     serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter,Global.UserTasks);
     xmlWriter.Dispose();
    }
    stream.Dispose();
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can still write those data in the app's folder without any special permissions.

Comment: @Astro. Yes Astro, I am saving the data in local folder only but still the xml is corrupt in above mentioned scenarios.

Comment: You need to block user from terminating the app while your stream is writing the file ?

Comment: While that is a simpler scenario (to block user from terminating app), I just cannot stop system from crashing/restarting because of OS errors/crashes line BOD.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a StorageStreamTransaction object to help guarantee that the file gets committed. If the app crashes before the transaction is committed the file system should roll back the file to it's initial state.

I'm not an XmlWriter expert so this is just pseudo code but hopefully this will point you in the right direction:

```
using (StorageStreamTransaction transaction = await file.OpenTransactedWriteAsync())
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof([Type]));

    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(transaction, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, [Object]);
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
    }
}
```

[StorageStreamTransaction class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagestreamtransaction.aspx)

The documentation can use some updates and I will see what I can do.

I hope this helps,

James

Comment: Thanks James. I will give it a try and see how it works in my app. Will get back to you with my observations. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Ohh my...it was much simpler than I expected and kind of miss from my side.
The CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting parameter was creating a new file and if app crashes between   the time when the file is created and the time when it is written using serializer.Serialize method, the  file created is corrupt and blank.
I replace the parameter with CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists and it worked, so if the file is failed to written in serializer.Serialize method, it still have the old data which is what I wanted.

I am still thinking about the scenario where ReplaceIfExisting parameter gonna be helpful because the way I see it now, OpenIfExists is more handy and useful.